# rich reviews plugin not working properly

Tags: wordpress, plugins, rating

i am using rich review plugin to create a rating system.what i want is to rate the different categories of a single product like looks,hair and teeth of a person for example,what i did was created a form in rich review and i want to use this code snippet `[RICH_REVIEWS_FORM category="person"]` with in a single page,it enables me to use this code snippet and even displays a three different forms,the problem is i can supply input through only one form,even if i change the category of the forms to different name,i can only supply input to only one of the form?

Answer (score -1):

This requires a patch from the plugin author, both for the JS that handles the form elements, and the $_POST submission of the form data.

> Essentially the patch allows you to have independent forms on the same page by using a shortcode parameter for a unique key. So for instance two forms on the same page might look like this.

```
[RICH_REVIEWS_FORM category="something" unique_key="one"]
[RICH_REVIEWS_FORM category="something_else" unique_key="two"]
```

See [this thread](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/impossible-to-have-two-o-more-rich_reviews_form-on-1-page?replies=9)

Comment: Instead of including links, summarize the most important points in your answer and include the link for additional reference.